# The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to generate a query set using one to many relationship via foreign key.I'm trying to obtain profile instance from current logged in user, then getting profile following, after than, I will extract post as well as comment. The associating models are:-

```
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#this is how profile of a sample user, say MAX looks like
class Profile(models.Model):
    Follwers=models.IntegerField(default='0')
        user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    bio=models.TextField(max_length=120,blank=True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    birth_date=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    verified=models.BooleanField(default=False)
        ProfilePic=models.ImageField(upload_to='UserAvatar',blank=True,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save() 

class FollowingProfiles(models.Model):
    Profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ProfileName=models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProfileName

class post(models.Model):
    Profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='PostMedia',blank=True,null=True)
    DatePosted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Content=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Profile.user.username

class comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 Content=models.CharField(max_length=120,null=False,blank=False,default='it is sapora')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Profile.user.username

#views.py
def feed(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        userfollowing=FollowingProfiles.objects.filter(Profile=profile)
        for following in userfollowing:
            username=following.ProfileName
            useraccount=User.objects.filter(username=username)
            mprofile=Profile.objects.filter(user=useraccount)
            Post=post.objects.filter(Profile=mprofile)
            comment=comment.objects.filter(post=Post)
            final_post_queryset=final_post_queryset+Post
            final_comment_queryset=final_comment_queryset+comment
        return render(request,'feed/feed.html',{'final_comment_queryset':final_comment_queryset,'final_post_queryset':final_post_queryset})
    else:
        return redirect('signup')
```

It produces following error:-
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with the code you have provided here.

First:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)  <--- Here
```

Profile has OneToOne relation with User. So it should be accessable via `request.user.profile`.

Also in later parts, you are mixing up queryset with Django Object and trying to conact them which does not make sense. If you want to see the comments and the posts, you can simply do that it template like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenitcated %}
    {% for post in user.profile.post_set.all %}
          {{ post }}
          {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
              {{ comment }}
          {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And this code will work in any template of your project. For reference please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/) for related objects.

#### Update

You can use [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relation to set the `following` in profile:

```
class Profile(models.Models):
    # rest of the code
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

And in template, show their posts like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenitcated %}
    {% for profile in user.profile.following.all %}
          {% for post in profile.post_set.all %}
              {{ post }}
          {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This code will only show post made by user but i also want to show post made by users he or she is following

Comment: In that case, you need to change your `FollowingProfiles`. Because it does not have any reference to other profile it is following(it only has reference to the user's profile only)

Comment: Can you suggest some changes then?

Answer (score 1):

```
profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
userfollowing=FollowingProfiles.objects.filter(Profile=profile)
```

`profile` must be Profile-object, not the Profile-queryset.